# A quotient stack question

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $X$ be a **proper** Deligne-Mumford stack, whose **normalization**, $X'$, is a **global quotient** stack (that is, a stack of the form [W/GL_n],where W is an algebraic space) with a **projective** scheme as a coarse moduli space.

**Question**:Is it true that 
$X$ is also a global quotient stack?

Comment: Two questions on your question: 

1) the normalization of a DM-stack is well-defined because normalization is an étale-local property, right ? is it well-defined for Artin stacks ?   
2) What are the reasons for your proper/projective assumptions ? Do you have easy counterexamples without them ?

Comment: @ACL:  Regarding the need for "proper", one silly observation is that one does, at least, need "quasi-compact".  Otherwise the disjoint union of $B\mu_n$ over all integers $n$ is a counterexample.  But this counterexample doesn't address, say, "proper" versus "quasi-compact and locally finitely presented over the base".

Comment: @ACL:  Also, I think the counterexamples of Edidin, Hassett, Kresch and Vistoli show why one should assume that $X$ is separated.  Still, I don't see why one should prefer "proper" to "separated, quasi-compact and locally finitely presented" for this question.

Comment: @Jason Starr: You are right. People believe that a stack with the conditions you mentioned above should be a quotient stack. In my situation I can also assume these extra conditions.

Comment: @ACL: in fact normalization commutes with smooth localization, hence is well-defined for Artin stacks. This is proved in Laumon and Moret-Bailly's book.

Comment: @matthew: My own feeling is that this case is probably no easier than the general case.